# Disable Default Arrow Key Scrolling Behavior To Remove jQuery.scrollTo() Jitter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, scrollto, smooth-scrolling

I am attempting to use the `jQuery` plugin `.scrollTo()` in order to smoothly scroll to specific potions of a webpage using the arrow keys. 
I.e. when down is pressed the browser will smoothly scroll to the next `div` in a list of `divs`. However, due to the fact that the arrow keys are normally bound to scrolling functiontality in web browsers, there is a **jittery effect** that results when an arrow key is pressed to trigger the `.scrollTo()` function.

It appears that when an arrow key is pressed, the browser first very quickly attempts to scroll normally without smoothing, and then very shortly afterwards begins to scroll smoothly via the `scrollTo()` function.

I would normally imagine that one might be able to simply `return false` for the keydown event in `jQuery` in order to prevent any scrolling from occuring, but this would prevent `.scrollTo()` from being triggered by arrow key presses as well.

Is there a **simple way to disable the deafult arrow key triggered scrolling behavior within a browser** in order to allow the arrow keys to only trigger `.scrollTo()` events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `.preventDefault()` prior to triggering `.scrollTo()` fixed the problem by preventing the default scrolling behavior which is normally triggered by the arrow keys.